# Sympy nsolve vs Mathematica NSolve for multivariate polynomial equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sympy, solver, polynomial-approximations

An interesting feature regardin NSolve[] with Mathematica is that it seems to provide all the solutions it can find (and hopefully it is exhaustive). For instance, as stated in [the examples](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html):

```
NSolve[{x^2 + y^3 == 1, 2 x + 3 y == 4}, {x, y}]
```

would return an array of 3 solutions.
From what I could try, it seems to scale quite well even for, say, 20 multivariate polynomial equations with 20 variables as it can be seen [in this notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/a710e8c8-2b78-4169-8089-265bc9815e7d).

Alternatively, I am quite found of using Sympy which also features a kind of [nsolve function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).
But there is a catch: this function requires a starting point "x0" and it would possibly find only one solution - and still, provided you are lucky enough to have chosen a proper x0.

Some users [suggested in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344471/sympy-nsolve-function-and-multiple-solutions) to use a "multi-start method" where one would choose a grid of potential starting points and run nsolve multiple times. But this doesn't seem to fit with my problem: if the grid is of size d for one variable, then it would scale exponentially as 20^d starting points for my own problems of 20 variables. It doesn't seem to match with Mathematica which seems to run in a blink.

What is mathematica doing to achieve such a fast solving? Is it due to the nature of the equations? (Maybe some Groebner basis computations behind the scene)
Could it be done with Sympy?

Thank you for your help!